# How do I get the labels.txt in vertex ai?

Tags: tensorflow, model, tensorflow-lite, google-cloud-vertex-ai

After I export the model as tf lite I only get the model.tflite. I already used to train images here before but it was way back in 2021 and when I export I got dict.txt back then and I just rename it to labels.txt.

I tried to manually create a labels.txt and put the label name alphabetically but it doesnt work
[here are the files I got before after I export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUPel.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just finding this now, hoping the post helps others. The order of the labels list in labels.txt *does* matter and it depends (apparently) on the order in which you added labels to your model. You are correct in that it is not an alphabetical list. Here is how I found the correct list order for my Vertex AI multi-label image classification model:

1. Go to the Google Cloud Console -> Vertex AI -> Model Registry
2. Click on the link to the trained model you exported
3. In the Confusion matrix on this page, your labels are listed according to the order they should be in your labels.txt file. The top axis reads from left-to-right and the left axis should read the same order from top-to-bottom.
4. Place these labels in your labels.txt file in this order, each label on a new line without commas etc.

For example, the confusion matrix's top line of labels reads:

```
'Purple, pizza, ping, pong'
```

Then the labels.txt file should read:

```
Purple
pizza
ping
pong
```

Cheers and hope this helps!